# Realm - Null objects cannot be copied from Realm

Tags: java, android, realm

Ошибка в копировании `user = realm.copyFromRealm(user);`
Ему явно нечего копировать. И прошу пояснить, в чем заключается проблема. Может я не правильно беру данные с реалма?

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
username = intent.getStringExtra("username");
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
user = realm.where(User.class).equalTo("username", username).findFirst();
user = realm.copyFromRealm(user);
realm.close();
```

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                           Process: com.happ, PID: 1138
>                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.happ/com.happ.controllers.UserActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null objects cannot be copied from
>   Realm.
>                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
>                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
>                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
>                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                            Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null objects cannot be copied from
>   Realm.
>                                                               at io.realm.Realm.checkValidObjectForDetach(Realm.java:1300)
>                                                               at io.realm.Realm.copyFromRealm(Realm.java:1013)
>                                                               at io.realm.Realm.copyFromRealm(Realm.java:987)
>                                                               at com.happ.controllers.UserActivity.onCreate(UserActivity.java:52)
>                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
>                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
>                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
>                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
>                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
>                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
>                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
>                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
>                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Видимо нема у вас в таблице юзера с таким имененм

Comment: а для чего используют  realm.copyFromRealm(user) ?

Comment: @KirillStoianov метод `copyFromRealm()` извлекает объект-модель, которая будет "отвязана" от БД. Изменения в такой модели не приведут к изменениям записей в самой БД (изменение записей, полученных через метод `where()` приводят к изменениям в самой БД). Немного [почитать про это](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1109197/WebControls/)

Comment: @pavlofff так вот как это делается, спасибо!